# Маппинг JSON c помощью GSON, часть модели не получает данные и все время Null

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Есть ответ от api в формате json:

```
"status": "ok",
"devices": {
 "538764": {
 "id": "538764",
 "name": "",
 "class_name": "Water",
 "device_sn": "7590054",
 "modem_id": "73d0a6",
 "device_time": null,
 "config_time": "1554455381",
 "timezone": "Europe/Moscow",
 "registrators": {
  "cold": {
  "id": "4635497",
  "name": "",
  "channel_id": "160",
  "unit_id": "m³",
  "offset": "0.0000",
  "modem_value": null,
  "last_value": "0.0760",
  "last_value_timestamp": "1615339629",
  "billing_init_value": "0.0520",
"billing_init_timestamp": "1583826840"
}, etc
```

Используя GSON пытаюсь замаппить ответ по моделям
Метод:

```
    public Devices parseFullElementInfo(String response){
        JsonObject object= JsonParser.parseString(response).getAsJsonObject();
        return gson.fromJson(object, Devices.class);
    }
```

Класс Devices содержит в себе `HashMap<Long, Device>`:

```
public class Devices {
    @SerializedName("devices")
    private HashMap<Long, Device> devicesMap;
    // getters
```

Класс Device содержит в себе класс Registrators:

```
public class Device {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private long id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("class_name")
    private String className;
    @SerializedName("device_sn")
    private long deviceSn;
    @SerializedName("modem_id")
    private String modemId;
    @SerializedName("device_time")
    private long deviceTime;
    @SerializedName("config_time")
    private long configTime;
    @SerializedName("timezone")
    private String timezone;
    @SerializedName("registrators")
    private Registrators registrators;
    // getters
```

Класс Registrators - это `HashMap<String, Registrator>`
Класс Registrator:

```
public class Registrator {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private Long id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("channel_id")
    private String channelId;
    @SerializedName("unit_id")
    private String unitId;
    @SerializedName("offset")
    private Double offset;
    @SerializedName("modem_value")
    private Double modemValue;
    @SerializedName("last_value")
    private Double lastValue;
    @SerializedName("last_value_timestamp")
    private Long lastValueTimestamp;
    @SerializedName("billing_init_value")
    private Double billingInitValue;
    @SerializedName("billing_init_timestamp")
    private Long billingInitTimestamp;
    //getters
```

Проблем: При использовании метода классы Deivces и Device получают значение без проблем, но данные не маппятся в Registrators, он остается null.
Данные registrators точно приходят в api ответе.
Предполагаю, что модель Registrators неправильная, но ошибку найти не могу.

Comment: В смысле `class Registrators extends HashMap<String, Registrator>`? Я точно знаю что Gson умеет работать с мапами, но с кастомными классами-наследниками вероятно нет. Попробуйте заменить на `HashMap` непосредственно.

Comment: @woesss нет, я наверное неправильно выразился. Имел ввиду 
`public class Registrators {
    @SerializedName("registrators")
    private HashMap<String, Registrator> registratorsMap;
}`

Comment: Нет, так не прокатит - класс-обёртка лишний, объявите `registratorsMap` непосредственно в `Device`

Comment: Можно и свою обертку, только тогда при создании gson через GsonBuilder нужно зарегистрировать адаптер для Registrators.class, который будет конвертировать этот класс в json и обратно.

Answer (score 0):

По совету @woesss, объявил `HashMap <String, Registrator>` непосредственно в `Device`:

```
public class Device {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private long id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("class_name")
    private String className;
    @SerializedName("device_sn")
    private long deviceSn;
    @SerializedName("modem_id")
    private String modemId;
    @SerializedName("device_time")
    private long deviceTime;
    @SerializedName("config_time")
    private long configTime;
    @SerializedName("timezone")
    private String timezone;
    @SerializedName("registrators")
    private HashMap<String, Registrator> registratorsMap;
```

После чего Gson начал маппить нормально, это оказалось решением проблемы.